# How to start and stop a periodical background task?

Tags: android

I need some help with android background tasks and scheduling.

I want to execute and destroy a periodical background-task by toggling a flag with an onClick event. The background task should read the **BLE RSSI** every second and show it in a toast.

Reading and showing RSSI is no problem.

If anybody can give me an example of how to do this it would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Handler to run periodic task:

```
private val handler = Handler()
private val rssiTask: Runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        readRssi()
        handler.postDelayed(this, period)
    }
}
private val period = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)

fun start() {
    handler.postDelayed(rssiTask, period)
}

fun stop() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(rssiTask)
}
```

or in Java:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable rssiTask = new Runnable {
    public void run() {
        readRssi();
        handler.postDelayed(this, period);
    }
};
private long period = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

public void start() {
    handler.postDelayed(rssiTask, period);
}

public void stop() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(rssiTask);
}
```

Comment: Thank You. :) But i need it in java. My Android/Java experiences very poor, and i've nerver used kotlin. Its my first Android Project.